# CMake linking error with OpenCV libraries

Tags: opencv, makefile, g++, cmake, vtable

I'm working on a project which uses OpenCV development libraries found on my package manager. I'm currently using two machines to work on this project, my laptop and my desktop. When I compile the code on my laptop, I have no issues. However, I'm getting a linking error on my desktop, which is strange because both machines have all corresponding libraries.

The error message complains about an undefined reference to a set of methods that should be getting linked, but cannot be found. Here's the output from cmake and make:

cmake:

```
 malak@bigblackbox:~/Dropbox/libcardreader/release$ cmake .. && make
 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
 -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
 -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
 -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
 -- Configuring done
 -- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to: /home/malak/Dropbox/libcardreader/release
```

make:

```
 Scanning dependencies of target test
 [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o
 [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/libimganalyzer.cpp.o
 [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/libcardreader.cpp.o
 Linking CXX executable test
 CMakeFiles/test.dir/libimganalyzer.cpp.o: In function `cv::MSER::~MSER()':
 libimganalyzer.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev[_ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev]+0xe): undefined reference      to `vtable for cv::MSER'
 libimganalyzer.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev[_ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev]+0x26): undefined reference      to `vtable for cv::MSER'
 libimganalyzer.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev[_ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev]+0x2e): undefined reference      to `VTT for cv::MSER'
 libimganalyzer.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev[_ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev]+0x55): undefined reference      to `cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
 libimganalyzer.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev[_ZN2cv4MSERD1Ev]+0x8a): undefined reference      to `cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[2]: *** [test] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`libimganalyzer.cpp` has an `#include` statement to reference `libimganalyzer.h` and here is what I reference in `libimganalyzer.h`:

```
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
```

If I use cat to look at the contents of `features2d.hpp`, which is where MSER is defined, it shows up:

```
 malak@bigblackbox:~/Dropbox/libcardreader/release$ cat /usr/include/opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp | grep MSER
 typedef struct CvMSERParams
     /////// the next few params for MSER of color image
 } CvMSERParams;
 CVAPI(CvMSERParams) cvMSERParams( int delta CV_DEFAULT(5), int min_area CV_DEFAULT(60),
 CVAPI(void) cvExtractMSER( CvArr* _img, CvArr* _mask, CvSeq** contours, CvMemStorage* storage, CvMSERParams params );
    /////// The class implements MSER algorithm introduced by J. Matas.
 class CV_EXPORTS_W MSER : public CvMSERParams
     CV_WRAP MSER();
     CV_WRAP MSER( int _delta, int _min_area, int _max_area,
     //! the operator that extracts the MSERs from the image or the specific part of it
     MserFeatureDetector( CvMSERParams params=cvMSERParams() );
     MSER mser;
 malak@bigblackbox:~/Dropbox/libcardreader/release$
```

and here is the output of my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
 set( CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
 project( test )
 find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
 add_executable( test test.cpp libimganalyzer.cpp libimganalyzer.h libcardreader.cpp libcardreader.h )
 target_link_libraries( test ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I'd like to know what it is I lack on my desktop that lets me compile this project on my laptop without a hitch.

Update: I've tried multiple scenarios in terms of `cmake` and `make` on both my laptop and desktop and here's the results if it helps any:

`cmake` on desktop; `make` on desktop: `cmake` is successful, `make` throws error above.

`cmake` on desktop; `make` on laptop: `cmake` is successful, `make` is successful. Project runs.

`cmake` on laptop; `make` on desktop: `cmake` is successful, `make` is successful. Project runs.

`cmake` on laptop; `make` on laptop: `cmake` is successful, `make` is successful. Project runs.

Comment: I am not sure but do you have ROS system in your PC which is missing in your laptop...i had the similar problem.

Comment: I have Debian on my laptop and Crunchbang on my desktop. Both are originally amd64 architecture builds and I have both set to be able to compile i386 packages via `dpkg`. ROS is based off Ubuntu, which in turn is based of Debian, so our issues might not be that different if you have a similar setup.

Comment: I am using 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) in my Laptop as well as in PC. And i have ROS hydro.

Comment: Did you at any point copy the release directory from your laptop to your desktop ? Do you get the same error when you delete your release directory and then run cmake/make ? Cmake stores information about libraries in its cache and has a hard time detecting changes (e.g. paths or version) for these libraries.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had used Dropbox to easily share my files between my desktop and my laptop since my file server was down. `cmake` works on both the desktop and laptop, but `make` only properly links the files on the laptop. The desktop outputs the same error seen above. What I tried is being will be added to the question up top.